# Saving JavaScript Variables on Refresh

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to save the variables `d`, `dps`, and `dpc` in different variables. How can I do this as simply as possible? I would also like to know how to access these as simply as possible. Thanks! I am creating a `document.getElementById` and adding to it with these variables.

Comment: What is "d, dps, and dpc"? Is that from some code you wrote? Have you looked up how to save data with Javascript? Have you heard of cookies or local storage?

Comment: Use the localStorage API.

Comment: Do some Google-fu on "javascript" and "cookies"

Comment: @MikeC I have done lots of "Google-fu" but I'm slightly new to Javascript and HTML so I couldn't really understand cookies so I asked to see if there was any other simpler way. It is from some code I am working on.

Comment: @MikeC See the comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `localStorage` API.

```
localStorage.setItem('d', "test Value 1");
localStorage.setItem('dsp', "test Value 2");
localStorage.setItem('dpc', "test Value 3");
```

If you open the console and check `localStorage` you can see these variables, and these will persist in the given domain.

`sessionStorage` will do the same thing, but `localStorage` will persist even when the browser is closed and reopened.

To recall these items you can use `.getItem()`.

For example `localStorage.getItem('d')` will return `"test Value 1"`

Comment: How do I call these?

Comment: When I add these I get a stacked version of the numbers instead of a combined version. For example, if d = 4 and dps = 50 and I add dps and d I get 450 instead of 54. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @DangerMouse5 that is because you are adding strings... change them to numbers by using `parseInt()` and they will add as numbers

Comment: How would I use that in an example like localStorage.d = localStorage.d + localStorage.dps

Comment: @DangerMouse5 `var answer = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('d')) + parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dps'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies.

take a look at this:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

A pretty common approach is using the `localStorage` Api of the browser to keep track of some data even when the window is refreshed.

You may want to look at this documentation: [HTML5 Storage - localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Also, you can use the `localStorage` API without the `getItem` and `setItem` call by just accessing and assigning values like you would on a plain object:

```
localStorage.firstname = "John Doe";
var myName = localStorage.firstname; //You should check if its set before accessing it

 localStorage.d = "Some value";
 localStorage.dps = "Some other value";
 localStorage.dpc = "Some other value aswell";
 localStorage.mySpecialFunction = function(){ return 1; };

 console.log(localStorage.mySpecialFunction()); // --> 1

 console.log(localStorage.d,localStorage.dps,localStorage.dpc);

//Checking if localStorage has a specific property:
 if(localStorage.dps) console.log('Something is in localStorage.dps!');
```

Note that this storage is persistent even when you refresh or close the browser, but it is not global to all sites, so for example facebook.com has a different `localStorage` instance than google.com has in your browser!

Comment: Is there a way I can access the localStorage without putting the .localStorage in from of the name?

Comment: You can do something like this: `var xy = localStorage` but that will only work for read actions AND will not keep track of new added or removed things. As localStorage is a API from the browser, the only way to access it is by using the `localStorage` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies, localStorage and sessionStorage

you will be able to test these examples in its console and you will be able to look at it in Resources, on chrome

Examples:

```js
document.cookie="username=John Doe";

localStorage.setItem("userName", "John Doe");
localStorage.getItem("userName");


sessionStorage.setItem("userName", "John Doe");
sessionStorage.getItem("userName");
```